# Remove 0 from array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I have this array `[08,09,10,11]` and I want to take off the 0 like this `[8,9,10,11]`
there's any method to do it or any short way?

Thanks!

Comment: Such array cannot exist in Ruby. A leading `0` denotes an octal number and both, `08` and `09` are invalid literals. Maybe your array contains strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an array strings - `["08", "09", "10", "11"]`, otherwise it doesn't make sense at all that they are not already valid integers (as you wish without the zero).

So in case you have strings, you can simply do

```rb
["08", "09", "10", "11"].map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [flaco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71767187/463206) - its easier than filtering on a variable length string of zeros

["08", "00","09", "10", "11"].map(&:to_i).delete_if {|item| item == 0}